# No internet connection

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet

OK so I installed 14.04 from a usb.  I downloaded it to from on computer and installed it on an old Dell 2006.  I had internet before installing, but now I have nothing.  No wireless and not internet using an ethernet cable.  What should I do?  Thanks for any help.  lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

Comment: are you getting any option for connecting to internet or in system settings?

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. Could you add more in detail as what you've tried so far? how do you see that the internet is not there? when you connect the ethernet cable, what error do you get.. etc?.. This will help us to assist you better. :)

Comment: I haven't really tried too much.  In the upper right hand corner there is a icon and no network connection.  I am a true beginner.

Comment: Edit your question to add the output from: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: @user307403 no open terminal window paste this command in there and then paste the output of the command in your question

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in UBUNTU 12, I couldn't get online with wifi or ether.  Luckily I had another laptop and I was able to download the latest drivers for the nic card and wireless device.  I put them on a USB and pulled them over to the UBUNTU machine and installed those drivers, I rebooted and everything worked.

Have you checked to make sure the installed drivers are the correct ones for the machine? Follow Wild Man's advise and post the output of

```
 lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

This will get you more specific help

Answer (score 0):

This have happened to me once when installing on a laptop. My problem was that internet connection (both wireless and wired) was disabled by a hardware switch.
If you are running on a laptop, look for something that looks like an antenna icon on the function keys. Hold "fn" and the other function key with that icon on it.

Hope this helps.